# bloc.io: failing XTCAssertTest for unknown reasons; previously successful in mock app

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, unit-testing

currently in bloc.io's iOS course. wrote a method that fails a test and I don't know why.

[background: been wrestling with this for 4 hours now, scoured stackOverflow and my course material to ensure I understood for loops, mutable strings, appending mutable strings, and putting an integer into a string.]

Using a basic app practice project that I use to test things out, I wrote a method using NSLog to verify what was in the string, and it worked like a charm.

When I copy and pasted the method to the bloc.io exercise, it failed a test that it doesn't seem to me like it should be failing.

1) What initially worked in my "practice app"

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)applicationdidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

NSMutableString* numberString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
for(int index=-7;index<=13;index++)
{
    [numberString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",index]];
}
NSLog(@"Content in MutableString: %@", numberString);
// return @"numberString";
return YES;
}
```

2) The output from #1:

```
Content in MutableString: -7-6-5-4-3-2-1012345678910111213 // so far so good
```

3) The "copy and pasted version" adapted for this exercise:

```
- (NSString *) stringWithNumbersBetweenNumber:(NSInteger)number andOtherNumber:(NSInteger)otherNumber
{
NSMutableString* numberString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
for(NSinteger index=number;index<=otherNumber;index++)
{
    [numberString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)index]];
}
//    NSLog(@"Content in MutableString: %@", numberString);
return @"numberString";
}
```

4) The test that is failing that I don't understand why:

```
- (void)testThatStringWorksAscending {
NSInteger lowNumber = -7;
NSInteger highNumber = 13;
NSString *expectedString = @"-7-6-5-4-3-2-1012345678910111213";
NSString *actualString = [self.counter stringWithNumbersBetweenNumber:lowNumber andOtherNumber:highNumber];
XCTAssertEqualObjects(expectedString, actualString, @"strings differed");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yarrrghh. Figured it out thanks to my awesome bloc mentor Steve. I shouldn't have used

```
    return @"numberString";
```

but rather:

```
return numberString;
```

Difference is a literal string vs. a variable, which I need to better understand..